# Open and collect informations from an email(Gmail) using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, gmail

I'm trying to do an automation that collects data from an appointment that its sent by email. In this email I get all client informations, like his name, cell number, service code, among another informations that I need. Using Selenium, I managed to get to the list with all the emails I want, but I cant open them to collect the informations. It doesn`t matter if its marked as read or unread. This is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    navegador = uc.Chrome()
    navegador.get("https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ifkv=ATuJsjxG3RsICDj2hkbEpG6FnLJeH5bdJvk0et0iCgOwQdwiQrCaIn1d843UZdamcUBsenELWsaPiw&rip=1&sacu=1&service=mail&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&dsh=S-501316531%3A1708951428733681&theme=glif")
```

Here, the login page from gmail is opened

```
navegador.find_element(By.NAME, "identifier").send_keys("email")
navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ").click()
sleep(6)
navegador.find_element(By.NAME, "Passwd").send_keys("password")
sleep(3)
navegador.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ").click()
```

with this one i manage to get logged in

```
sleep(5)
navegador.find_element(By.ID, ":lt").click()
```

here I click at the label that gets all the appointments emails in one place. From now on, I don`t know what else to do so I can indentify the unread emails, open these emails individually and then collect and store the data. If anyone know hot to help or if its not possible, I would really apreciate an answer. Thanks.

I`ve already tried to identify the emails by using the name "unread, ". I've tried several times but without suceed.